How to override the properties of the default profiles provided by the Config Server without bootstrap?
For examples, I want to configure spring.jpa.ddl-auto as "none" in my application without bootstrap.
Config Server
spring.jpa.ddl-auto: validate

Application(i.e. config client)'s application.yml
spring:
  config.import: "optional:configserver:"
  jpa.ddl-auto: none

props of specified profiles are override well, but props of default profile is not working.
